# How can I stop full page HTML from being cached?

Tags: 8, caching

I am having an issue with my whole page's HTML being cached. This is getting in the way of some dynamic block content that is based off of a user preference value (both authenticated and anonymous users).

I have located the cache entry in the cache_render table of the DB and it has a CID of:

```
http://dev-mysite.pantheonsite.io/:html
```

(this would be the entry for the front page)
I do have the block that builds this dynamic content configured with cache settings:

```
[#cache]['contexts'] = ['session', 'user'];
[#cache]['max-age'] = 0;
```

I am only having this caching issue when code is push to the Pantheon servers, local development environments with default cache config settings do not have this issue.

Comment: Apparently Pantheon, [uses Varnish cache](https://pantheon.io/docs/varnish/) which is probably caching the entire page.

Comment: I have confirmed with Pantheon that Varnish is not caching the pages.

Answer (score 10):

(Anyonymous) Page cache can not be controlled by max-age or contexts. You need to call \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger(); to prevent that kind of caching.

However, if it is a block that is displayed on all pages, then that becomes pretty pointless to even try and you could uninstall the page_cache module completely.

Comment: Where would I need to use the page_cache_kill_switch service? in the block as it is built? preprocess alter?

Comment: Doesn't matter where exactly as long as it is called on every request. The block should work if you disabled caching of the block with max-age 0. Another thing to consider to not affect performance of the site would be to move the dynamic part of that block to another request, that you trigger with JS.